# AngularJS controller success, window.location not closing modal or refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reload, angular-controller

I want the current page im on to refresh and close the modal after I submit a form...I think I got it to refresh by adding a changing variable to the end of the url, but the modal 'grey out' aspect of the screen doesn't go away...and for that mater the url in the browser doesnt change. The console.log shows Im getting to the 'success' - any thoughts?

My controller looks like this

```
$scope.addChild = function() {
    var pid = $scope.child.parent_id;
    $http.post('/api/child/', $scope.child)
    .success(function(response) {
        window.location.href='#/parent/details/'+pid+'?dt='+getTime();
    });
}
```

Per request - here is the complete code...

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

/* --------------------------------------------
    ROUTES
 --------------------------------------------*/
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
    })
    // parents
        .when('/parents', {
            controller:'ParentController',
            templateUrl: 'views/parents.html'
        })
        .when('/parents/details/:id',{
            controller:'ParentController',
            templateUrl: 'views/parent_detail.html'
        })
        .when('/parents/add',{
            controller:'ParentController',
            templateUrl: 'views/parent_add.html'
        })
        .when('/parents/edit/:id',{
            controller:'ParentController',
            templateUrl: 'views/parent_edit.html'
        })
    // childs
        .when('/childs', {
            controller:'ChildController',
            templateUrl: 'views/childs.html'
        })
        .when('/childs/details/:id',{
            controller:'ChildController',
            templateUrl: 'views/child_detail.html'
        })
        .when('/childs/add',{
            controller:'ChildController',
            templateUrl: 'views/child_add.html'
        })
        .when('/childs/edit/:id',{
            controller:'ChildController',
            templateUrl: 'views/child_edit.html'
        })
    // catch-all
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

ChildController.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log('Child Controller called...');
    $scope.loading = false;


    $('#parentAddChildModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        var modalParentId = $scope.child.parent_id;
        $location.url("parents/details/"+modalParentId);
    })



    $scope.getChilds = function() { console.log('getChilds called...');
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get('/api/child')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.childs = response;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }

    $scope.setChildWithParentId = function(oid) { console.log('setChildWithParentId called...w/'+$routeParams.id);
        $scope.child = {
            parent_id: $routeParams.id
            ,name: ''
            ,username: ''
            ,email: ''
            ,password: ''
            ,address: {}
            ,phone: ''
        };
    }

    $scope.getChild = function() { console.log('getChild called...');
        var id = $routeParams.id;console.log('gonna get /api/childs/'+id);
        $http.get('/api/child/'+id)
        .success(function(response) {console.log('getChild response...'+id+'->'+response);
            $scope.child = response;
        });
    }

    $scope.addChild = function() { console.log('addChild called...');
        console.log($scope.child);
        $http.post('/api/child/', $scope.child)
        .success(function(response) {
            window.location.href='#/childs';
        });
    }

    $scope.addChildWithParent = function() { console.log('addChildWithParent called...');
        console.log($scope.child);
        var oid = $scope.child.parent_id;
        $http.post('/api/child/', $scope.child)
        .success(function(response) {console.log('addChildWithParent called...Success:'+oid);
             $('#parentAddChildModal').modal('hide');
        });
    }

    $scope.updateChild = function() { console.log('updateChild called...');
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.put('/api/child/'+id, $scope.child)
        .success(function(response) {
            window.location.href='#/childs';
        });
    }

    $scope.removeChild = function(id) { console.log('removeChild called...');
        $http.delete('/api/child/'+id)
        .success(function(response) {
            window.location.href='#/childs';
        });
    }

    $scope.getParents = function() { console.log('getParents called...');
        $http.get('/api/parent')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.parents = response;
        });
    }

    $scope.getInstruments = function() { console.log('getInstruments called...');
        $http.get('/api/instrument')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.instruments = response;
        });
    }

    console.log('Child Controller loaded...');

}]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp" >

<head>

    <title>myApp - DEV</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="navbar-header" >
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" >
                    <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" >myApp - DEV</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li><a href="#/childs" >Childs</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li><a href="#/parents" >Parents</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-12" >
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="/app.js" ></script>

    <script src="/controllers/parent.js" ></script>
    <script src="/controllers/child.js" ></script>


</body>
</html>
```

parent_detail.html

```
<a href="#/parents" >Go Back</a>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getParent()" >
    <div class="panel-heading" >
        <h3 class="panel-title" >
            {{parent.name}}
            <div class="pull-right" >
                <a href="#/parents/edit/{{parent._id}}" >Edit</a> | <a href="#" ng-click="removeParent(parent._id)" >Delete</a>
            </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-md-4" >
                <p>Account Info</p>
                <ul class="list-group" >
                    <li class="list-group-item" >Username: {{parent.username}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" >Email: {{parent.email}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" >&nbsp;</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" >
                <p>Childs
                    <span class="pull-right"  style="padding-right: 25px">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#parentAddChildModal">
                            Add Child
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="parentAddChildModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content" ng-controller="ChildController" ng-init="setChildWithParentId()" >

            <form ng-submit="addChildWithParent()" >

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >
                    <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only" >Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="parentAddChild" >
                    Add Child
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body" >

                <div class="form-group has-error" >
                    <label>Parent ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm disabled " ng-model="child.parent_id" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-error" >
                    <label>Name:*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="child.name" placeholder="Name" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-error" >
                    <label>Email:*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="child.email" placeholder="Email" >
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" > Close </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
            </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

edited to reflect current state - still not closing the modal

Comment: which type of modals are you using here? Bootstrap Modals???

Comment: yes bootstrap modal

Comment: ok, try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect using `window.location.href`, it will not let angular router know about location changes. So ultimately digest cycle won't run and application state doesn't change.

Consider using `$location.path` to navigate within the SPA. Calling `path` method will let router know about application route changed and finally it updates state properly.

```
//First close the modal|
$(modal).hide();
$location.path('#/parent/details/'+pid+'?dt='+getTime());
```

Comment: will i need the dt=getime() to force a non-cached url if i use this...?

Comment: @jpmyob do you have route registered with pattern `/parent/details/:pid`?

Comment: yes, it is the identical route that is in the url to start, I get to a parent' detail page @ /parent/detail/the_id and on that page there is a modal for i use to add a child, all that works, it's going into db correctly etc, I get the success console.log...but no refresh and modal form disappears but the grey out overlay of 'modal' sticks around....

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller

```
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log('Child Controller called...');
    $scope.loading = false;


$('#parentAddChildModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    var modalParentId = $scope.child.parent_id;
    $location.url("parents/details/"+modalParentId);
})

$scope.getChilds = function() { console.log('getChilds called...');
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/api/child')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.childs = response;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
}

$scope.setChildWithParentId = function(oid) { console.log('setChildWithParentId called...w/'+$routeParams.id);
    $scope.child = {
        parent_id: $routeParams.id
        ,name: ''
        ,username: ''
        ,email: ''
        ,password: ''
        ,address: {}
        ,phone: ''
    };
}

$scope.getChild = function() { console.log('getChild called...');
    var id = $routeParams.id;console.log('gonna get /api/childs/'+id);
    $http.get('/api/child/'+id)
    .success(function(response) {console.log('getChild response...'+id+'->'+response);
        $scope.child = response;
    });
}

$scope.addChild = function() { console.log('addChild called...');
    console.log($scope.child);
    $http.post('/api/child/', $scope.child)
    .success(function(response) {
        $('#parentAddChildModal').modal('hide');
    });
}

$scope.addChildWithParent = function() { console.log('addChildWithParent called...');
    console.log($scope.child);
    var oid = $scope.child.parent_id;
    $http.post('/api/child/', $scope.child)
    .success(function(response) {console.log('addChildWithParent called...Success:'+oid);
        //window.location.href='#/parents/details/'+oid+'?dt='+getTime();
        //$location.url('/#/parents/details/'+oid);
        //$route.reload();
    });
    $('#parentAddChildModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
       $location.url('parents/details/'+oid);
    })
}

$scope.updateChild = function() { console.log('updateChild called...');
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.put('/api/child/'+id, $scope.child)
    .success(function(response) {
        window.location.href='#/childs';
    });
}

$scope.removeChild = function(id) { console.log('removeChild called...');
    $http.delete('/api/child/'+id)
    .success(function(response) {
        window.location.href='#/childs';
    });
}

$scope.getParents = function() { console.log('getParents called...');
    $http.get('/api/parent')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.parents = response;
    });
}

$scope.getInstruments = function() { console.log('getInstruments called...');
    $http.get('/api/instrument')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.instruments = response;
    });
}

console.log('Child Controller loaded...');

}]);
```

Comment: I tried this, once each with the route.reload and the location.url...it neither refreshed nor got rid of the modal...

Comment: can you please mention the html code and the complete controller code???

Comment: and also the route declaration

Comment: what happened??

Comment: Tried your changes - no change

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have controller looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('sampleApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('sampleAppController', function ($http, $scope, $route)
```

See this above in .controller add $route function and now your code looks like:

```
$(modal).hide();
$route.reload();
```

Change the order of jquery file, it will work now

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" >

<head>

    <title>myApp - DEV</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="navbar-header" >
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" >
                    <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" >myApp - DEV</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li><a href="#/childs" >Childs</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li><a href="#/parents" >Parents</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-12" >
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="/app.js" ></script>

    <script src="/controllers/parent.js" ></script>
    <script src="/controllers/child.js" ></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried that route.reload, no change...or more specifically, the modal form dissappears, but the grey'd out modal effect stays....

Comment: did you add $route function inside? .controller function? which looks like in my above answer, add $route inside your controller

Comment: ok that means your modal hide is not working, did you tried correct modal id? to close the modal? like $('your modal hide').hide();

Comment: ok, i injected $route into the controller, and the page 'appears' to reload - but the modal isn't closing. yes, I used the $('#the_correct_modal_name').hide()

Comment: see my updated answer, change the order of your jquery link, in index.html file

Comment: edit your question now, which you tried with correct controller with modal name,